# ObservableCollection and UnhandledException with unspecified error in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

I have the following code where if i remove the ´Task.Delay´ it throws an UnhandledException with message "Unspecified error".
This exception is not thrown from the actual code and will not be captured by any try catch.

```
ViewModel Code:

ObservableCollection<Data> _newData;
ObservableCollection<Data> _oldData;

List<Data> dataList = await Task.Run(() => GetData());

foreach(var dataItem in dataList)
{
    if(dataItem.Type == DataType.New)
        _newData.Add(dataItem);
    else        
        _oldData.Add(dataItem);

    await Task.Delay(1); // Comment out and code fails
}
```

This only happens as the´dataList´ grows large enough.

Comment: Have you initialized _oldData and _newData collections?

Comment: yes. Its not a null reference error from the code. Wrapping everything in try catch all do not work or catch anything.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? Does this happen in `wpf`, `windows-phone-8.1` and `winrt-async`?

Comment: There is no stacktrace or other info in the unhandled exception. It happens in Windows Phone 8.1 RT. The exception is cought in App.UnhandledExceptionHandler. No try catch in my code catches it.

Comment: Do you have any event handler bound to your collections ? The error may come from one event handler trying to alter the collection while some new items are added...

Comment: @Vincent there is nothing special about it. It happens when there is to many elements in the list. putting in some delay fixes it. The Observable collections is bound using a normal Binding from the Xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a completely unrelated issue.

Replacing a `MenuFlyout` with a `Flyout` solved the problem. I am unsure why exactly.

Answer (score 0):

_newData and _oldData are not initialized (null) so you might need to instanciate them to see if you still have the issue.

Also, you are using ObservableCollection so I guess you bind them on the UI: make sure you are not in another thread (use the Dispatcher) before adding items to the collections.